# auto-generate method calls to every member object of a class

Tags: c++

I would like to be able to 'forward' a member function call of a class to every member variable of the class:

```
class MyObject {
    X_Behavior v1;
    X_Behavior v2;
    ...
    Y_Behavior v10;
    Z_Behavior v11;
    ...
public:
    void clear() { v1.clear(); v2.clear(); ... v10.clear(); v11.clear(); }
    void hide()  { v1.hide();  v2.hide();  ... v10.hide();  v11.hide();  }
    void show()  { v1.show();  v2.show();  ... v10.show();  v11.show();  }
};
```

All these functions are implemented in every component class,
according to the expected 'behavior'.
e.g.

```
class X_Behavior {
public:
    void clear(); 
    void hide();
    void show();
    ...
};
```

Manual copying if these iterations

```
    void clear() { v1.clear(); v2.clear(); ... v10.clear(); v11.clear(); }
    void hide()  { v1.hide();  v2.hide();  ... v10.hide();  v11.hide();  }
    void show()  { v1.show();  v2.show();  ... v10.show();  v11.show();  }
    ... more similar members here ...
```

is hard to maintain and review.

There are many classes like `MyObject`, each with many member variables.
Many developers edit them.
Also, you cannot tell whether an ommitted call or a mixed order was intentional or not.

Can you propose a compiler-generated construct that allows me to implement these functions once and not touch them again?

```
void MyObject::clear() {  /* call clear() for every (_Behavior) member of this class */ }
void MyObject::hide()  {  /* call hide()  for every (_Behavior) member of this class */ }
void MyObject::show()  {  /* call show()  for every (_Behavior) member of this class */ }
```

- I do not wish to increase the size of `MyObject`.
- The `*_Behavior` classes should stay as they are.
  Not to be tied to a base class.
- I want to do this without employing the Preprocessor.
  Can you propose a C++11/17/20 solution for this?
- *Ideally*, I would like to see if this could be done with minimal code, just like
  the compiler generated default implementations for constructor, copy constructor, assignments, destructor.

Comment: If each Behavior has `clear`, `hide`, `show` it seems like adding an interface base class is the way to achieve this (though I note that you objected to this). Then you could simply have `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<<IBehavior>> behaviors` then you can `for (auto& behavior : behaviors) behavior->clear();` for example

Comment: @CoryKramer, adding runtime overhead and heap allocations just for the sake of code safety is a way to do it. I am sure that there exists a safer syntax to do the same withoug any overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### 1. `std::tuple` + `std::apply`

A simple C++17 solution to your problem would be to add an additional method that returns references to all behaviors, then you can use `std::apply` with a templated lambda to reduce it to the individual calls.

e.g.: [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/xahc95a1M)

```cpp
class MyObject {
    BehaviorA v1;
    BehaviorA v2;
    BehaviorB v3;
    BehaviorB v4;

    constexpr auto behaviors() { return std::tie(v1, v2, v3, v4); }

public:
  void clear() {
      std::apply(
          [](auto&&... behavior) { (behavior.clear(), ...); },
          behaviors()
      );
  }
};
```

Pros:

- Easily optimizeable by compilers, will mostly result in the same code as the manual function calls

Cons:

- You have to remember to add each new behavior to `behaviors()`.

---

##### 2. `boost::pfr::for_each_field`

If you don't mind using boost you can enhance this by putting all the behaviors into an aggregate struct (since C++14 (but C++17 makes it a lot easier) you can sort-of reflect the members of aggregates by using aggregate initialization - this is often called "magic tuple")

e.g.: [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/4ssEcn1cn)

```cpp
struct BehaviorA { void clear() { std::cout << "CLEAR A" << std::endl; } };
struct BehaviorB { void clear() { std::cout << "CLEAR B" << std::endl; } };

class MyObject {
    struct MyObjectBehaviours {
        BehaviorA v1;
        BehaviorA v2;
        BehaviorB v3;
        BehaviorB v4;
    } behaviors;

public:
  void clear() {
      boost::pfr::for_each_field(behaviors, [](auto&& behavior) {
          behavior.clear();
      });
  }
};
```

Pros:

- Very hard to mess up with this one
- Can be optimized very good

Cons:

- Needs boost

###### 2.1 magic tuples without boost

You can also do the same without using boost, you'll have to write quite a bit of code though:

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/7f7ed4634)

```cpp
template<class T>
concept aggregate = std::is_aggregate_v<T>;

struct any_type {
    template<class T>
    operator T() {}
};

template<aggregate T>
consteval std::size_t count_members(auto ...members) {
    if constexpr (requires { T{ members... }; } == false)
        return sizeof...(members) - 1;
    else
        return count_members<T>(members..., any_type{});
}

template<aggregate T>
constexpr auto tie_struct(T& data) {
    constexpr std::size_t fieldCount = count_members<T>();

    if constexpr(fieldCount == 0) {
        return std::tie();
    } else if constexpr (fieldCount == 1) {
        auto& [m1] = data;
        return std::tie(m1);
    } else if constexpr (fieldCount == 2) {
        auto& [m1, m2] = data;
        return std::tie(m1, m2);
    } else if constexpr (fieldCount == 3) {
        auto& [m1, m2, m3] = data;
        return std::tie(m1, m2, m3);
    } else if constexpr (fieldCount == 4) {
        auto& [m1, m2, m3, m4] = data;
        return std::tie(m1, m2, m3, m4);
    } else {
        static_assert(fieldCount!=fieldCount, "Too many fields for tie_struct! add more if statements!");
    }
}

template<aggregate T, class Callable>
constexpr void for_each_field(T& data, Callable&& callable) {
    std::apply([&callable](auto&&... members){
        (callable(members), ...);
    }, tie_struct(data));
}

struct BehaviorA { void clear() { std::cout << "CLEAR A" << std::endl; } };
struct BehaviorB { void clear() { std::cout << "CLEAR B" << std::endl; } };

class MyObject {
    struct MyObjectBehaviours {
        BehaviorA v1;
        BehaviorA v2;
        BehaviorB v3;
        BehaviorB v4;
    } behaviors;

public:
  void clear() {
      for_each_field(behaviors, [](auto&& behavior) {
          behavior.clear();
      });
  }
};
```

Pros:

- Same as above

Cons:

- Needs a lot of boilerplate code (but that can also be used for other things - structure reflection is always useful :D )

---

##### 3. `std::variant` array

With `std::variant`s you can combine all your behaviors into a single array (it's basically an union of all possible behaviors), then you can use a simple for-loop with `std::visit` to access the individual behaviors:

e.g.: [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/Gz993s5vf)

```cpp
struct BehaviorA { BehaviorA(int) {} void clear() { std::cout << "CLEAR A" << std::endl; } };
struct BehaviorB { BehaviorB(float) {} void clear() { std::cout << "CLEAR B" << std::endl; } };

class MyObject {
    using Behavior = std::variant<BehaviorA, BehaviorB>;
    Behavior behaviors[4];

public:
  MyObject() : behaviors {
      Behavior{std::in_place_type<BehaviorA>, 1},
      Behavior{std::in_place_type<BehaviorA>, 2},
      Behavior{std::in_place_type<BehaviorB>, 1.0f},
      Behavior{std::in_place_type<BehaviorB>, 2.0f}
  } {

  }

  void clear() {
      for(auto& b : behaviors)
        std::visit([](auto& behavior) {
            behavior.clear();
        }, b);
  }
};
```

Pros:

- Easy to use, no allocations

Cons:

- If you want to access only a single element it gets hairy, e.g.:
  `auto& b = std::get<BehaviorA>(behaviors[0]);`
- No names for the individual behaviors, only array indices
- Potentially wastes a lot of memory (if some behaviors are a lot larger than others)

Comment: Oh, that looks great. The contra isn't one if it's suitable to store the behaviours as a tuple right within `MyObject` – as they are private anyway...

Comment: 2.1 is exciting. Could you please explain how  `m1`, `m2`, etc emerge in the picture? I did not see any declarations nor template arguments... Could you point me to a page (in the standard?) that explains this mechanism? is there a term for this?

Comment: @GrimFandango it's commonly called "magic tuple" - using [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) for `count_members()` to detect how many members a given struct has, then using [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) (case 3) to break the struct apart into it's individual members. The only gotcha is that you need to write a structured binding expression for each possible count of members, since structured bindings don't support parameter packs yet unfortunately.

Comment: [Reflection for Aggregates](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2020/10/01/reflection-for-aggregates/) is a good read, it goes through building something like this step-by-step :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best option is to create a base class for the `Behavior` classes. If you really want to avoid that, you could store them as `unions` (or `std::variant`s, but it would make the code needlessly more complicated and less readable.

Comment: `std::variant` uses type-erasure to do that. Why would one need heap allocation and dynamic dispatch just to iterate?

Comment: @GrimFandango `std::variant` needs no heap allocations, it contains a [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) that is as large as the largest type that the variant can hold. So no additional allocations, but you'll need extra code to check for the exact type in the variant (or use `std::visit`), so not optimal either