# Convert from two tuples of any type ==> a tuple of pairs, automatically

Tags: c++, reflection, c++17

I want some kind of reflection in C++17.

To test its power and limitation, I created a custom copy constructor that copies only int and float.

However, I don't know how to automatically merge tuples.

By using power of `getAllFields()`, please edit code (only) in "vvv" section to make it automatic.

MCVE :: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/457e91d9a0469be8

```
class B{public:
    int c1;
    std::string c2;
    float c3;
    constexpr auto getAllFields() {
        return std::tie(c1, c2, c3);
    }
    static auto getAllFields_pair(B& b1, B& b2) {
        ///vvv insert your code here 
        //     but please don't call c1/c2/c3 by variable names directly
        return std::tuple<
            std::tuple<int&,int&>
            ,std::tuple<std::string&, std::string&>
            ,std::tuple<float&,float&> >{
            std::tuple<int&,int&>{b1.c1,b2.c1}
            ,std::tuple< std::string&, std::string&>{b1.c2,b2.c2}
            ,std::tuple<float&,float&>{b1.c3,b2.c3}
        };
        ///^^^ edit (only) here  
    }
```

Here is how I call it ::-

```
    static void copyIntAndFloatToB2(B& b1, B& b2) {
        auto f=[](auto& b1_cx,auto& b2_cx){
             using typee=std::remove_reference_t<decltype(b1_cx)>;
             if constexpr(std::is_same_v<typee,int> || std::is_same_v<typee,float>){
                b2_cx= b1_cx;
             }
        };
        
        std::apply(
          [&f](auto&&... aField) { 
              (
                  f(std::get<0>(aField),std::get<1>(aField))
              , ...); 
              
            },
          getAllFields_pair(b1,b2)
      );
   }
};
```

Here is its usage ::-

```
int main(){
    B b1;
    B b2;
    b1.c1=5;
    B::copyIntAndFloatToB2(b1,b2);
    std::cout<<b2.c1<<std::endl;  ///: print 5
}
```

I am very new to `std::tie` and `std::apply`.

The above code is extended from  [auto-generate method calls to every member object of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464826/auto-generate-method-calls-to-every-member-object-of-a-class/70465408#70465408)

Comment: Why are you restricting possible answers when you don't know whether that makes sense or not? Why are you copying function names from the other post that makes no sense here?

Comment: @Passer By :: Thanks!  I believe that such restriction make senses.  If it is not, I feel that generous people here will help me by pointing out and violating it anyway.      By the way, I have improved function names / variable names.  They were really bad like you mentions, thanks!     It would be nice if you take a look.  ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a merge function which merges two tupes of arbitrary types but with the same amount of object as follows:

**C++17**

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename... Args1, typename... Args2, std::size_t ... Is>
    auto merge_tuples(std::tuple<Args1&...> t1, std::tuple<Args2&...> t2,
                      std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::make_tuple(std::tie(std::get<Is>(t1), std::get<Is>(t2))...);
    }
}

template<typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
auto merge_tuples(std::tuple<Args1&...> t1, std::tuple<Args2&...> t2) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args1) == sizeof...(Args2));
    return detail::merge_tuples(t1, t2, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args1)>());
}
```

[DEMO C++17](https://godbolt.org/z/453fe9v9K)
Then you can replace your code in `getAllFields_pair` by

```
return merge_tuples(b1.getAllFields(), b2.getAllFields());
```

*How does it work?*

1. what we want is `std::make_tuple(pair1, pair2, /*and so on...*/)`, where `pairI` is the `I`-th element from both tuples.
2. each pair can be constructed with `std::tie(std::get<I>(t1), std::get<I>(t2))` Note tie is important, as we want to keep a pair of references.
3. to construct the list of pairs needed by `std::make_pair` pack expansion can be used. As the only thing which changes between two pairs is their index of `std::get`, we need a template pack of indices. Thus template the implementation function on `std::size_t ...Is`, a pack of indices.
4. then the pack expansion can be done via `pair<Is>...` (pair as shorthand for tie(get, get))
5. putting it all together, an index pack needs to be crated and passed to the function somehow to let the compiler deduce `std::size_t ...Is`. this can be done nicely with `std::make_index_sequence` with `sizeof...(Args)` as the amount of indices to generate.

**C++20** introduces constraints and templated lambdas, allowing for the following much nicer function, where the `static_assert` is replaced by `requires` and the separate function can be replaced by a templated lambda.

```
template<typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
    requires (sizeof...(Args1) == sizeof...(Args2))
auto merge_tuples(std::tuple<Args1&...> t1, std::tuple<Args2&...> t2) {
    return [&]<std::size_t ... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::make_tuple(std::tie(std::get<Is>(t1), std::get<Is>(t2))...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args1)>());
}
```

[DEMO C++20](https://godbolt.org/z/Ecv6recG3)

If you want to merge tuples without references, then just provide a second overload where the arguments of the function are changed from `std::tuple<Args&...>` to `std::tuple<Args...>`.