Any way to name tuple items?
A tuple can we written as the following:
auto tp = std::tuple<int, bool>();

I have a lot of them and they each have a comment above them naming what each element represents, E.g.
//age, is_alive
auto tp = std::tuple<int, bool>();

Is there a way to do something like this instead?
auto tp = std::tuple<int age, bool name_exists>();

I need tuples as I am recursing through the items at compile time using std::get with an index. This cannot be done using structs. No part of my code's functionality requires knowing the name of the element (this makes something like using a std::map with std::any a bit absurd, for example). This is only for readability and to provide a more natural seeming interface.
Update: I feel this question may be brought up as a duplicate. To clarify, I do NOT need to access the elements by name. I only want the name for readability. I could modify that code, but have the names separated by commas seems worse than having comments above the code.
Another update: One may suggest using keeping the comments as the best solution. The issue with the comments is that they are always indented differently from the tuple definition. This means to see the element which corresponds to the name, one must count them. This is the main issue I am attempting to resolve. Consider this example:
//account_ptr, uid, sender, subject, date (seconds from epoch), read, flagged
using SomeTuple = std::tuple<"tag_for_this_tuple", std::string, int, std::string, std::string, std::string, bool, bool>;


@Eljay I already explained I cannot use structs because I need to recurse through elements via index.

How about... using age = int; using name_exists = bool; auto tp = std::tuple<age, name_exists>();

auto tp = std::tuple<int /*age*/, bool /*name_exists*/>();

@Eljay I mean, technically that would work... but I have around 70 of these and the parameter names are often repeated. With an average of two to three elements per tuple, that makes like 200 of those definitions. Moreover, then we wouldn't know the type of the element.

@IgorTandetnik good point...

Perhaps you want [this}(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464826/auto-generate-method-calls-to-every-member-object-of-a-class) instead.

It's possible to iterate over struct members with names, see boost.pfr.

"I cannot use structs". You can, then you have to provide tuple compatibility, see structured_binding
